# R parsing string

Tags: json, r, parsing, rcurl

I did a request using RCurls and is giving me the token I need. The answer for the request is the following:

```
r<-POST(url,body = data)
content(r)
"{\"token\" : \"WiKuxCc2VboCLBc_MbtKrKtDkJnDSntrGjYrazbgs1FRX_BAj-p2gadILBNhk9JBti0m6o_i7DYaqf4R4i2xPh1TedYWpCrINShiFrB7xabbv8zT-8LCBTUau14HPZzv\",\"expires\" : 1425681647918,\"ssl\" : false}"
```

How can I parse this string that I've got from `content(r)` to get only the Token?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the function `POST` is from `httr`, not `RCurl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is JSON format:

```
library(rjson)
json <- "{\"token\" : \"WiKuxCc2VboCLBc_MbtKrKtDkJnDSntrGjYrazbgs1FRX_BAj-p2gadILBNhk9JBti0m6o_i7DYaqf4R4i2xPh1TedYWpCrINShiFrB7xabbv8zT-8LCBTUau14HPZzv\",\"expires\" : 1425681647918,\"ssl\" : false}"
x <- fromJSON(json)
x$token
[1] "WiKuxCc2VboCLBc_MbtKrKtDkJnDSntrGjYrazbgs1FRX_BAj-p2gadILBNhk9JBti0m6o_i7DYaqf4R4i2xPh1TedYWpCrINShiFrB7xabbv8zT-8LCBTUau14HPZzv"
```